# Proof via Semantic Equivalence $(p \lor q) \land (q \implies p) \equiv p$

Tags: logic

> $$(p \lor q) \land (q \implies p) \equiv p$$

Struggling to solve the above with Semantic Equivalence

step 1: implication $( p \lor q ) \land ((\lnot q) \lor p)$

step 2: distributivity
$((p \lor q ) \land \lnot q) \lor ((p \lor q) \land p)$

step 3: absorption.
$((p \lor q ) \land \lnot q)) \lor p$

step 4: distributivity
$((\lnot q \land p) \land  (\lnot q \land q)) \lor p )$

step 5: absorption $((\lnot q \land q) \land p )$

step 6: negation $p \lor T$

Not sure where to go from here? Can $p \lor T$ be resolved to $p$?

Comment: $p \lor T \equiv T$.  But you made a mistake in the use of the distributive property between step 3 and step 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 4 should be $$\begin{align}(4) \quad &\equiv  ((p \land \lnot q) \lor \underbrace{(q\land \lnot q)}_{\text{F}}) \lor p\tag{distrib.}\\ \\  (5)\quad  &\equiv (p \land \lnot q) \lor p \\ \\(6)\quad &\equiv  p\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi amwhy! Nice to see you doing well on solid ground!